# ngx-translate if a key is missing in one of the json file replace with other json file same key

Tags: json, angular, angular8, ngx-translate

I have a scenario, I have two languages files `en.json & es.json` I have a key in `en.json` file which is missed in `es.json` file, however, I want to replace this missing key with the `en.json` key how would I achieve this.

I know the way we use MissingTranslationHandler for missing keys, but I do not want to show a default text for missing keys, Although I'm doing this for a missed key from both files, in my scenario its different.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your app module constructor, you can tell what is the default language which you're interested in

```
export class AppModule {

    constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
        translate.setDefaultLang('en');
        translate.use('en');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, actually I was doing this on AppModule but as I'm using multiple modules language files separately, Now I have realized from your answer that I have to update default language across the modules. Thanks again.